# Magento 2 has stopped showing related products on front end product page

Tags: product-view, magento2.1.6, related-products

Our related products are not showing on the front end no longer. They did and looked good however it does not work no more.

Can anyone help?

Comment: No information to work with. What are you using for a theme? What are your related product settings? What did you research? Just 'It doesn't show anymore' is not enough information.

Comment: My theme is showing Parent Theme: Magento luma Theme Path: Mandy/mandystools (which is what my developer set up). I have no idea what my related product settings are, where do I find these? My cross-sells are showing. Can I ask you what you are referring to by "what did I research? "

Comment: Well just what did your research? Did you check any log filles or anything with information that might help us help you. Also Mark makes a good point about reindexing your website but it also can be dat for instance an update is not compatible with your theme or its just a bad theme or your theme has a setting that someone disabled or changed or anything like that.

Comment: @Mandy, why don't you just ask your developer?

Answer (score 1):

We have had some difficulties in related products now showing in the past that were resolved by rebuilding our product data indexes.  Have you tried rebuilding indexes yet?  If not, it could be related to templates, etc. which would require more information.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that product stock available,then check that product website. If all is good then do reindex and cache flush then check it.

If still not working then enable luma theme and check it.if working then your theme issue. Also check log file.

Hope it will help you.